# Spring boot project with multiple maven modules

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

can someone tells me how to create a spring boot project with multiples  modules in eclipse IDE?
My project structure will look like this

- parent-ui (spring boot projet)
- module-jpa
- module-service

and so on .
Thanks

Comment: create a multimodule maven project... and include spring boot as dependency into the parent pom and declare de managed dependencies into the module poms as you need. next import the project into eclipse as existent maven project

Comment: the configuration of the datasource i have ti include it in application.properties in the parent project or in the module-jpa ?

Comment: application.properties of boot project

Comment: thanks for your help johnny

Comment: your wellcome :) .. I going put this as an answer can you validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Multimodule Maven Project, include spring boot as dependency into the parent pom and declare de managed dependencies into the module poms as you need. next import the project into eclipse as existent maven project